# How to pass a value through button to another activity in android code?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I have two class DashboardActivity.class and ProfileActivity.class,

In Dashboard class I would like to pass a value through button to ProfileActivity class. But it keep getting me error and the response JSON telling me that the 'Required field(s) is missing'. When I checked, the value from Dashboard didn't pass to ProfileActivity, that's why the response keep telling me 'Required filed(s) is missing'.

My, question is, How to pass a value through button to another activity. I already use this code :

```
btnLinkToProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
btnLinkToProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

    //userFunctions.userProfil(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
    startActivityForResult(i,0); 
}
```

But I get forced close when I try to run.
Here's the complete code of Dashboard Activity :

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
Button btnLinkToProfile;
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */       
    // Check login status di database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
   // user already logged in show dashboard
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

      //JSONObject json = jParserr.getJSONFromUrl(dashboardURL, "GET", params);

        btnLinkToProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);

        btnLinkToProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

                //userFunctions.userProfil(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);

                //startActivity(i);
                //finish();


            }

        });
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);             
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Keluar dari dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }        
}
```

}

And here's for ProfileActivity class :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        // Loading user Profile in Background Thread
        new showUserProfile().execute();
    }

    ///...       



  /**
   * Background Async Task to Load user profile by making HTTP Request
   * */
 private class showUserProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

      /**
       * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
       * */
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Profile. Please wait...");
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();
      }

      /**
       * getting user profile from url
       * */
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

          //String name = name.getText().toString();
          // Building Parameters
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          // getting JSON string from URL
          JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(profileURL, "GET", params);

         /* UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();


          if (params.length != 0)
                  return null;
          JSONObject json = userFunction.userProfil(params[0]);
          return json; */

          // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
          Log.d("User Profile: ", json.toString());

          ...
          return null;
      }



  }
}
```

Comment: In your `DashboardActivity` did you try `String name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();` inside the `Button` click? instead of `String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();` ?

Comment: @Shobhit Puri Yes, I already put String name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString(); in clickListener in the Button.

Comment: would this code even compile?  How can you cast a TextView to a String? Also, why post a million lines of unnecessary code?

Comment: @user2310289 It's compiled. But getting error when I click the Button profile. The type of variable name is String. I just trying to get the variable from TextView. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why haven't you showed us the part where you are retrieving the value? I'd prefer not to fish around your entire class looking...

Comment: @mikeyaworski I've edited my post. and I'm trying retrieve the value in doInBackground process.

Comment: You have a String parameter in doInBackground() and you're not passing anything when you execute() it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new Intent in the Profile Activity.

You should actually use getIntent() to receive the intent the activity was called with.

That will return an intent object with your "name" extra.

**EDIT:** Actually, I can't tell precisely where you are trying to read the value sent from the Dashboard.

In ProfileActivity you should have

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Then you can use the name from Dashboard in Profile.

Also look into implementing onNewIntent() for ProfileActivity.

**EDIT:** I edited your post to re-include where you call the AsyncTask. Notice your AsyncTask accepts a String parameter but you don't pass it one.

So do this in your ProfileActivity.onCreate():

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
new showUserProfile().execute(name);
```

Now in your doInBackground you should be able to get the name with args[0]

**EDIT:** Your AsyncTask should probably be:

```
 private class showUserProfile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
```

Because you only accept the parameter, other don't use the progress or return values.

Comment: I'm trying to read the sent value in private class showUserProfile, in doInBackground for getting user profile from url.

Comment: Did you try the two lines of code I suggested? I think that will work for you.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to show you how to read the intent and pass it to AsyncTask

Comment: I already compile, but it getting force close. It said it getting error in Onclick listener in dashboardActivity

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the extra properly, you just aren't retrieving it at all from  your next activity.

Use `Bundle var = getIntent().getExtras()`

followed by

```
if(var != null){
    myString = var.getString(KEY_NAME);
}
```